# How to setup apache multi-site with multi-domain on ec2

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, domain, web-hosting

Say I have two document roots domain1/ and domain2/

I know how to access those two roots from my own computer if they are hosted on the same computer. My question is that if I want to do the same thing on my ec2 server, how should I configure my elastic ips to those two roots? I know by default the elastic ip will only associate to the root with the name localhost(127.0.0.1).

Anyone could give me a detailed answer? An example would help, thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to do name based or IP based virtual hosting?

Comment: May I know how to do both? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just create 2 virtual hosts on your EC2 instance like:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /www/domain1
ServerName domain1
ServerAlias www.domain1

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /www/domain2
ServerName domain2
ServerAlias www.domain2

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Say I have www.domain1.com for the /www/domain1, and www.domain2.com for the /www/domain2. How can I redirect those two www domains to those roots on my ec2? What's the addresses shall I use to point to?